# What's the cutoff point for data when I refresh a Full or Partial copy Sandbox?

Tags: data, sandbox-refresh

When I refresh my Full Copy Sandbox, I press "refresh" and it takes a while to build the refresh.

Users are doing things to the database all the time. So some records change during the build of the refresh.

What state is the data in when the refresh is ready? Do my records look like

- When I pressed refresh?
- When the refresh completed?
- Whatever state each record was in at the point the refresh process saw it?

Comment: I know that I've had problems with sandbox data sometimes where the parent record in a relationship is not copied but the child is. This manifests itself as a child record with a lookup value that isn't valid, usually meaning that you can't delete or modify the child because the system can't re-evaluate the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they will be addressing this issue in the summer 15 release.  Full notes [here](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_deployment_sandstorm.htm).

> New Post-Copy Framework
>   If a production organization changes during sandbox creation or refresh, the sandbox can contain data inconsistencies. The new automated post-copy process quickly fixes these inconsistencies after copying is complete and tracks the fixes.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be the third option in my experience. I think is when the refresh process actually started after it has been waiting for a while in the queue.

Comment: I'd say it kind of has to be this one - otherwise the system would have to have some sort of sophisticated way of marking records as don't sync - and there's no good reason to do that.